# How to make a div opaque?

Tags: html, css

My smiley `div` has a `background color`, `z-index:999`, `opacity:1` to 1, however, you can still see the text through it :

Result is : [image: it is RED, opaque, ABOVE text chat and ... it is still visible !]

Relevant Code :

```
#smileyWindow {
    z-index: 999;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: -160px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


<div id="smileyWindow">
    <img class='smileyImage' src='img/smileys/{D)}.gif'>
    <img class='smileyImage' src='img/smileys/{adios}.gif'>
    <img class='smileyImage' src='img/smileys/{angel}.gif'>
    <img class='smileyImage' src='img/smileys/{angry}.gif'>
</div>
```

How can I make it opaque ?

Look at **hello world** text, which is still visible behind the `#smileyWindow`.

How is that possible ?

Comment: Is your div transparent or the text is on the div but under the smileys?

Comment: no element is transparent !
All elements are opaque: how a div whose background is RED and is layed ABOVE the text can show text ?

Comment: Can you show it on fiddle, hard to help you without other elements' css properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

- Add `position: relative;` to `#smileyWindow`.
- Make sure that`#chatText` is not having a higher `z-index`.
- Try absolute positioning for `#smileyWindow`